# Overriding the path of a submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Right now I have a submit button and the code looks like this

`<%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary btn-shadowed smallButton" %>`

I want to specifically point that button to my `signup_path`. What's the correct syntax for doing so? Googling hasn't helped and because of deploy constraints, I can't run this locally or deploy to heroku (it's a long story, not something that I can help in this situation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the path in your form, submit just submits the form it belongs to.

If you don't want to control it by the form, perhaps you want a link instead of a submit button, you can still style the link like a button.

See here for details on changing the form http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: How do I structure it to submit to the form correctly though, if I were to go with a link rather than a button?

Comment: If you are trying to submit the form, then changing the action in the form is the way to go. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp